# Linked List Assignment Mutation

Tags: python, linked-list

I have a question about how mutation works in linked lists with binding assignment.

Suppose we have the following linked list data type in python:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
```

Suppose we have an object `a` and bind `curr` to `a`:

```
a = ListNode(1, ListNode(2))
curr = a
```

Both are 1 -> 2 ->. Now if I try to mutate `curr`:

```
curr.next = ListNode(3)
curr = curr.next
```

Now `a` is 1 -> 3 -> while `curr` is 3 ->.

Here comes the part where I get confused. If I keep updating `curr` by:

```
curr.next = ListNode(4)
curr = curr.next
```

Now `a` is 1 -> 3 -> 4 -> while `curr` is 4 ->.

I'm wondering why would `a` be updated in this way?

Comment: Why do you expect `a` to not be affected?

Comment: what do you want to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because after

`curr = a`, `curr` and `a` are the same object.

And then, after

`curr = curr.next`, `curr` and `a.next` are the same object, which you can see by looking at the IDs (or even better, by going retro and drawing boxes and arrows with pen and paper :)

```
In [8]: id(curr)
Out[8]: 4509135032

In [9]: id(a.next)
Out[9]: 4509135032
```

Hence when you then modify `curr.next`, you are also modifying `a.next.next`.

Comment: Thank you so much! My confusion has now been cleared.